# Creating a stored procedure to export selected columns in a row as a delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a piece of code which allows me to take a single string and parse it into columns. However I have no idea where to start with the export. The import is easy enough with a split and insert.

With the export I will need to select about 6 of the 12 columns in table A, combine all these files into a delimited list and then return the string.

I assume that the best way of doing this would be the following?:

- Create the export procedure
- Create a temp table(e.g. "temp")
- DECLARE the values I want to export
- Insert into the "temp", a delimited string with all the values (i.e.  new row = "col1,col2,col3,col4") (*this is the part i'm not sure about*)
- Somehow return this value from the stored proc?

I'm fairly comfortable using SQL to select, update, combine and other menial tasks... but I literally have no idea when it comes to stored procs as I always try to avoid them and add functionality into my code instead!

Comment: Will the end result be a file being created from your application by calling the stored procedure? Is it just the export you want and there is no application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT
        ISNULL(Col6 ,'')
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col7 ,'')
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col8 ,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col9 ,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col10,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col11,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col12,'')  AS MyList
FROM MyTable
```

You can cast or convert different datatypes using SQL. ([Cast & Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx))
Here's a few examples:

```
SELECT
        ISNULL(CAST(Col6 as varchar) ,'')
+ '|' + ISNULL(CAST(Col7 as varchar(10)) ,'')
+ '|' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),Col8) ,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(7),Col9 ),'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col10,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col11,'') 
+ '|' + ISNULL(Col12,'')  AS MyList
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This will work ok, but my Columns have varying types. i.e. BIGINT, VARCHAR, FLOAT,.... the final output will be a VARCHAR though

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Code:

```
   declare

   function f
   return varchar2
   is
      l_text varchar2(1000);
   begin
      for c in (
      select rownum from <table>
      )
      loop
         l_text := l_text || c.rownum || ';';
      end loop;

      return l_text;

   end;

begin
   dbms_output.put_line(f); 
end;
/
```

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson thanks, I have requested to update the post to reflect this incase somebody else has this issue with Oracle instead of Server.